# Profile hover card to show user to follow or view profile

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am trying to build profile hover card on my website with button to follow and un-follow user, I am able to build this till the hover part, but hover card is getting disappeared when I move out of my profile thumbnail, how can i fix this to make hover card stay on mouseover and disappear on mouse-out

[image: Sample UI image]

[plunker link](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/lofozJOnkcd0JPEz)

Update: I am able to achieve it and update plunker for reference so that someone in future can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are adding/removing the HTML with a JS hover event. The reason it is disappearing is because once you are off of the thumbnail, it is telling your JS to remove the hover card HTML.

I would suggest making sure your hover card is a child element of the profile thumbnail. Use CSS to show/hide on hover rather than using JS to add/remove the HTML. The idea behind this is that if your hover card is wrapped inside the profile thumbnail, then you are still technically hovering over the thumbnail element when you move over to the card element.

Comment: i did try that, but the position of hover is not aligned with browser so i made it inside

Answer (score 0):

Your card disappears because `(mouseout)="hideprofile(d)"` is attached to the circular image. Once your mouse leaves the image it will hide the card. The best solution is to not hide the card on mouseout but with a click or another condition.

Here's a working example of how it could be done. Now it only hides the card when you click on it. And to prevent multiple cards spawning next to each other I added `this.data.map(item => { item.showpop = false })` into your showprofile() method to hide all the other cards.

https://plnkr.co/edit/MBROv0KeK4BNv0xv

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i need to hover and follow who ever i like so i may hover on any profile, and follow one of them, and hover should stay if i want to follow a person, and in your updated code, it showing even when you are not hovering on thumbnail and closes when i only click on it, in some cases i may even not follow but only check user details and i want hover to close when i am out of it

Comment: Then you should just create a close button and put the hideprofile() function trigger when you click that. Or make a timer function so the card only disappears 3 seconds after you mouseout. The code example was just to help it stop disappearing.

Comment: I have achieved it using css, and update the solution so someone with same requirement can have it.